# Remove first octet from IP address with Regex split

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to remove the first octet including the leading `.` from an IP address, I'm trying to use Regex but I cannot figure out the proper way to use it.  Here is my code

```
'47.172.99.12' -split '\.(.*)',""
```

The result I want is

```
172.99.12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` character has a special meaning in a Regex pattern: it matches any character except a newline.  You will need to escape it in order to match a literal period:

```powershell
'47.172.99.12' -split '\.(.*)',""
                       ^
```

Note however that this will return more results than you need:

```powershell
PS > '47.172.99.12' -split '\.(.*)',""
47
172.99.12

PS >
```

To get what you want, you can index the result at `1`:

```powershell
PS > ('47.172.99.12' -split '\.(.*)',"")[1]
172.99.12
PS >
```

---

That said, using Regex for this task is somewhat overkill.  You can simply use the [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead:

```powershell
PS > '47.172.99.12'.Split('.', 2)[1]
172.99.12
PS >
```

Comment: The `-split` operator allows restricting the number of resulting elements too. You could do `$head, $tail = '47.172.99.12' -split '\.', 2` (or `$null, $tail = ...` if you're not interested in the first octet).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - True.  But I meant more that Regex is inherently less efficient than the `Split` method (albeit not by much in such a simple case).  I don't like to use Regex solutions unless I need to match a variable pattern.  For static text though, I prefer the built-in string methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the 3 last numbers you can use the following regex :

```
(\.\d+){3}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI8jV7/2)

But if you want every things after the first dot you can use a positive look-behind :

```
(?<=\.).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI8jV7/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-replace` operator instead of `split`:

```powershell
'47.172.99.12' -replace '^\d+\.',""
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised, given the context, that no one mentioned the `[ipaddress]` class for this. Using this approach also ensures that the string is a valid IP Address.

```
$ipAddress = "192.168.0.1" -as [ipaddress]
If($ipAddress){
    ($ipAddress.GetAddressBytes())[1..3] -join "."
} Else {
    Write-Host "Invalid Address"
}
```

`-as` will attempt to convert the string to `[ipaddress]`. If successful the cast is performed else `$null` is returned. Then we use `.GetAddressBytes()` to break the IP address into its 4 parts. Since we know at this point it is a valid IP then we can safely rejoin the last 3 parts with a period.