# Substring IP-Address with adding a string generates error but works

Tags: powershell, substring, ip-address, lastindexof

I have following command:

```
$IP_start = $First.Substring(0, $First.LastIndexOf('.'))+ ".200"
```

`$First` is an IP-Address, for example 192.168.0.1

I want to change the 1 in the fourth octect into a 200.

```
Write-Output $IP_start
```

gives me the correct IP-Address 192.168.0.200, but at the same time I get the following Error:

> Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Substring" mit 2 Argument(en):  "Die Länge
>   darf nicht kleiner als 0 (null) sein. Parametername: length" In
>   *ps1:31 Zeichen:3
>   +   $IP_start = $First.Substring(0, $First.LastIndexOf('.'))+ ".200"
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

English translation

> Exception when calling "substring" with 2 arguments: "The length can not be less than zero. Parameter name: length" In * ps1: 31 characters: 3...

I think everything is working fine, but that error messages bothers me.

//edit:

There's an ip.txt, where each line is like "192.168.0.1; ABCDEF"

```
$txt = Get-Content ip.txt
$editline = foreach ($Data in $txt) {
  $First, $Second = $Data -split ';' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'

$IP_start = $First.Substring(0, $First.LastIndexOf('.'))+ ".200"
Write-Output "modify ipaddr_first $IP_start"
}

$editline | Out-File "$output"
```

$first is therefore "192.168.0.1" and $second is "ABCDEF".

Comment: What is the result of `$First.LastIndexOf('.')` on its own? I cannot reproduce your issue so something is different. LastIndex of will return -1 if it did not find anything so that would cause the issue. You tell us what $first is but we have to guess how you populated it. In either case I would say use the `[ipaddress]` type to help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061062/remove-first-octet-from-ip-address-with-regex-split/30067004#30067004

Comment: Substring is important to the question so it should be left in the title. Just makes a poor verb

Comment: What problem are you solving? Extracting a substring of an IP address string doesn't tell you a network ID (that depends on the network mask).

Comment: I just updated my opening post. I explain how $first is filled with values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions

```
$IP_start = "192.168.1.1"
$IP_start -replace "\d{1,3}$","200"
```

This will change any `192.168.1.xxx` by `192.168.1.200`

Comment: I changed it to 
$IP_start = $first -replace "\d{1,3}$","200"

so I can continue using my variable.
thank you!

Comment: To this solution, I still have a question: Why does the replace only changes the last number and not the other ones? E.g. IP-address 1.1.1.1 changes to 1.1.1.200. Why not 200.200.200.200? The regex is only looking for "1", doesn't it?

Comment: In that case "\d" means digits only, "{1,3}" means 1 to 3 digits only and at least "$" means the end of the string which finally means "replace a number that contains 1, 2 or 3 digits at the end of the string by 200". In the case of an IP Address, it will replace only the last numbers before the last "."

Answer (score 1):

```
$IP_start = "192.168.1.1"
(($IP_start -split "\.")[0..2] -join ".") + ".200"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Synthetic Method for an IPAddress Object , a fun way of doing this...

```
$Method = {
Param(
[Int]$Number,

[ValidateSet(1,2,3,4)]
[Int]$Position
)

$OctetPosition = $Position - 1
$CurrentIpAddress = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
$This.IpAddressToString -Split '\.' | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $CurrentIpAddress.Add($_) | Out-Null
}

$ChangedOctet = [Int]($CurrentIpAddress[$OctetPosition]) + $Number

if( $ChangedOctet -gt 255 ){
    throw "Resulting octet is $ChangedOctet which is greater than 255"
}

$CurrentIpAddress.Item($OctetPosition) = $ChangedOctet


return ($CurrentIpAddress -join '.')

}

$IPAddress = [System.Net.IpAddress]'192.168.1.1'
$IPAddress | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name Add -Value $Method

#$IPaddress.Add($Number,$OctetPosition)
$IPAddress.Add(200,4)
```